# A script built upon the requests module produces gibberish content after issuing a get request with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in Python to get the readable response content from ***[the map](https://csrd.maps.arcgis.com/apps/instant/sidebar/index.html?appid=685e92e3dd764236847fc52d4c295fb1)*** of a webpage using the requests module. However, When I run the script, all I get is unintelligible stuff.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://services5.arcgis.com/wjH30HL7rqC55zVw/arcgis/rest/services/Development_Variance_Permits/FeatureServer/0/query'

params = {
    'f': 'pbf',
    'cacheHint': 'true',
    'maxRecordCountFactor': 4,
    'resultOffset': 0,
    'resultRecordCount': 8000,
    'where': '1=1',
    'orderByFields': 'OBJECTID_1',
    'outFields': 'OBJECTID_1',
    'outSR': 102100,
    'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://csrd.maps.arcgis.com/apps/instant/sidebar/index.html?appid=685e92e3dd764236847fc52d4c295fb1',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

res = requests.get(link,params=params,headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.content)
```

The content the script produces is like (truncated):

```
b'\x12\xe9N\n\xe6N\n\nOBJECTID_1\x12\x0e\n\nOBJECTID_1\x10\x01B\x07\x08\xd4\x9d\x06\x10\x91\x1eb(\x12\x12\t-C\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a?\x11-C\x1c\xeb\xe26\x1a?\x1a\x12\t\x00\x00\x00@\x04\x1cs\xc1\x11\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x14\xd7|\xc1j\x18\n\nOBJECTID_1\x10\x06\x1a\x08OBJECTIDz\x14\n\x02(\x01\x12\x0e\x1a\x0c\xd0\x91\xbb\x94\xf6\x03\xe7\xcd\xd7\x96\xb9\x15z\x14\n\x02(\x02\x12\x0e\x1a\x0c\xd0\x91\xbb\x94\xf6\x03\xe7\xcd\xd7\x96\xb9\x15z\x14\n\x02(\x03\x12\x0e\x1a\x0c\xd0\x91\xbb\x94\xf6\x03\xe7\xcd\xd7\x96\xb9\x15z\x14\n\x02(\x04\x12\x0e\x1a\x0c\xd0\x91\xbb\x94\xf6\x03\xe7\xcd\xd7\x96\xb9\x15z\x14\n\x02
```

> What can I do to make the content understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified output format in `"f"` parameter as `pbf`, so you get binary data. Specify it as `Json` to get Json result back (more about the format here - [official doc](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/output-formats.htm))

```py
from pprint import pprint

import requests

link = "https://services5.arcgis.com/wjH30HL7rqC55zVw/arcgis/rest/services/Development_Variance_Permits/FeatureServer/0/query"

params = {
    "f": "json",  # <-- use Json here to get result in Json format
    "cacheHint": "true",
    "maxRecordCountFactor": 4,
    "resultOffset": 0,
    "resultRecordCount": 8000,
    "where": "1=1",
    "orderByFields": "OBJECTID_1",
    "outFields": "OBJECTID_1",
    "outSR": 102100,
    "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "referer": "https://csrd.maps.arcgis.com/apps/instant/sidebar/index.html?appid=685e92e3dd764236847fc52d4c295fb1",
}

res = requests.get(link, params=params, headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.text)
```

Prints:

```
200
{"objectIdFieldName":"OBJECTID_1","uniqueIdField":{"name":"OBJECTID_1", ...
```